# How to prevent Chrome quietening background tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm studying a language course while listening to piano music. I have the language course tab focused, and YouTube in the background. When the language course plays voice audio, Chrome suddenly quiets the background music, then jerkily turns the music back up when the voice finishes.

Can I disable this feature? It disrupts my concentration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Google support](https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/4821953?hl=en&authuser=1&msgid=4846515), this feature is called 'audio focus'.

There used to be a flag to turn it off chrome://flags/#enable-audio-focus-enforcement but unfortunately it's no longer available (August 2020).

Here's a bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1107805